Send custom notification to community user in a Build Your Own (LWR) community
Hello,
I work on a Build Your Own (LWR) community and we would like to send custom notifications to community users to be displayed when they are connected on the community.
I am wondering if there is an out of the box Salesforce feature to do it?
I found about creating a Salesforce flow to send custom notification but what about the UI (because we use a custom interface)?
Because it's a Build Your Own (LWR) community, it means everything is custom, I don't think we can use the standard way.
Do you know a solution?
Regards
